# Setting recaptcha in a different language other than english

Tags: recaptcha

Is it me or is recaptcha images cannot be translated to another language other than EN?
I have [image] and it is still in English. Is this intentional?

Answer (score 34):

For reCAPTCHA 2. Since a while have passed

**This is your link to cdn** *look at the end, `hl` parameter*

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=myCallBack&render=explicit&hl=fr" async defer></script>
```

**This is your captcha inside the form**

```
<div id="recaptcha1"></div>
```

**This is your javascript** 
*you can specify the lang code here too, I assume one of them is enough*

```
var recaptcha1;
var myCallBack = function() {
    //Render the recaptcha1 on the element with ID "recaptcha1"
    recaptcha1 = grecaptcha.render('recaptcha1', {
    'sitekey': '6LdJLws_your site key',
    'lang' : 'fr'
   });};
```

You can add multiple reCAPTCHAs with this method.

Here is full language reference:
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/language?hl=en

Comment: This solution works fine. Please refer here for the [Language codes](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/language?hl=en)

Comment: Worked for me, I only needed to add the param hl=fr in the script tag call. Thanks !

Comment: First tried with the `'lang' : 'bn'`, din't work for me. Then tried with the `&hl=bn` worked nicely.

Comment: What about reCAPTCHA 3? Is it fetching the default language of user's browser?

Comment: @DanielDanielecki I checked the documentation and it is not really clear how.

Comment: @atilkan it's not clear to me as well, was hoping that maybe you'll know. Thanks for checking, +1 for it :)

Answer (score 17):

Just to minimize the answers above.

It's not necessary to additionally add another `<script>` saying the same as you already do with your html (reCAPTCHA) element. Changing the link of the API will also work.

`<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?explicit&hl=nl"></script>`

For me I've changed the language code to `nl`(dutch) after `&hl=`.
But you can find your own language code at:
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/language

Comment: thanks it worked for me by using like this https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=tr

Answer (score 8):

replace `lang` to `hl` and it'll work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var recaptcha1;
var myCallBack = function() {
    //Render the recaptcha1 on the element with ID "recaptcha1"
    recaptcha1 = grecaptcha.render('recaptcha1', {
        'sitekey': '6LdJLws_your site key',
        'hl' : 'fr'
    });
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 7):

For recapture 2 just add script file with your language:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=fr" async defer></script>
```

Language codes here: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/language

Answer (score 3):

You just have to add this function above to your theme's `function.php` file and all done. It really works for me, you can change translation language by modifying country code in `hl` parameter.

Here i'm using `es` here for Spanish translation.

This is a list of language country codes: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/language

```
function wptricks24_recaptcha_scripts() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'google-recaptcha' );

    $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js';
    $url = add_query_arg( array(
        'onload' => 'recaptchaCallback',
        'render' => 'explicit',
        'hl' => 'es'), $url ); // es is the language code for Spanish language

    wp_register_script( 'google-recaptcha', $url, array(), '2.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wpcf7_enqueue_scripts', 'wptricks24_recaptcha_scripts', 11 );
```

Comment: Just open the functions.php file of your current theme and paste the below mentioned code, you can modify it to any of the language, just look at the above code we are using ‘hl’ => ‘es’ where “es” is the language code for Spanish language. We can create this recaptcha with few more languages at a time by applying the conditions to the code. We just need to pass the language code of our choice to “hl” parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Look at this page, rolling down and you will get the answer : 
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/customization

On your page where you show up the captcha for clients, within the `<form>` and before the reCaptcha widget, you add this code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var RecaptchaOptions = {
   lang : 'fr',
};
</script>
```

The following languages are supported:

English en / Dutch nl / French fr / German de / Portuguese pt / Russian ru / Spanish es / Turkish   tr

Hope it helps you...

Comment: I did that but the "stop spam" is an image and not a text. It's not translated eventhough lang = fr

Comment: I could not install reCaptcha for my existing form (without plugin), there was no explication and it was too much for my php knowledge, also you say that you can not change the language... so, try this one, i use this one now, you will noy have problem with the language : [link](http://www.phpcaptcha.org/)

Comment: The doc page not exists, and the `RecaptchaOptions` not working.