# Is it possible to change the reCAPTCHA language in different page?

Tags: wordpress, recaptcha

I am using wordpress and WPML to make websites, and I apply reCAPTCHA under the contact form.

My website is mainly in Chinese, so the reCAPTCHA shows "I am not a robot" in Chinese.  But after I duplicate the page into other languages, it still shows the wording in Chinese.

I'm wondering is there any way to change the wording of "I am not a robot" in English?

Thanks a lot for helping!!
[image]

Comment: See this i think you are looking for this its there in stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18859857/setting-recaptcha-in-a-different-language-other-than-english

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*User1121883*'s solution is for the old text reCaptcha v.1.0, not [the modern behaviour reCaptcha](https://webscraping.pro/no-captcha-recaptcha-challenge). It has limited customization options now.
So if you want to change other language for other custom language page you'll need to play with [reloading](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display) it with other language that would have different `hl` GET parameter:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=en-GB"></script>
```

### Update

I've done it client-side ([demo](http://testing-ground.webscraping.pro/recaptcha.html)), but you may do it server-side or also use this client side code.

```
<button class="btn" onclick="btnclick();return false;">Load reCaptcha in Chinese</button>
<script>
function callback() { console.log("Chinese reCaptcha loaded"); }
function btnclick()
{       
        s = document.createElement("script");
        s.src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=zh-CN";
        if(s.addEventListener) {
          s.addEventListener("load",callback,false);
        } 
        else if(s.readyState) {
          s.onreadystatechange = callback;
        }
        // we remove the inner html of old reCaptcha placeholder 
        var oldRecaptcha=document.getElementById('g-recaptcha');         
        while (oldRecaptcha.firstChild) {
            oldRecaptcha.removeChild(oldRecaptcha.firstChild);
        }
        document.body.appendChild(s); 
}  
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and inspiration!
I am trying a simple way to call different scripts on the header and it works!!

Answer (score 1):

reCAPTCHA has a number of built in translations. You can use these by setting the lang parameter of the RecaptchaOptions:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var RecaptchaOptions = {
   lang : 'fr',
};
</script>
```

You can find more here:
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/customization?hl=en#i18n

Comment: Is there any chance of you summarizing the content at the end of that link? There are many people, myself included, who can't visit that (or most) links because we are in work and that makes your answer useless to us. Also, the link may die and the percentage of people that you've helped will then drop to zero. Ty

Comment: @EngineerDollery is it ok now?

Comment: @user1121883, this solution doesn't work at my [recaptcha test](http://tarex.ru/testdir/recaptcha/recaptcha.php). Why?

Answer (score 0):

I am using WordPress 5+, at wp-config.php

```
$locale='sv_SE';
```

(For example, in the case of the Swedish language)

[image]